# Where is a Service Reference located after I move files to a different computer for automation?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, automation

I have a Web Services Project on one computer that has Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 on it. I automated these tests on a different computer using MSTest. I created a container and reference the files located in a folder. Recently my Service References changed. I have tryed taking the changed Service Reference files and the app.config file and adding those to the project but the tests are still not the ones being executed(with the new service reference they still use the old one)? How do I make the newest Service reference for the automated project. I have added the files to the main file the debug the release the object debug/release. Is there somewhere else to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you don't need all the service reference files. Most importantly there are 2 things:

1. Reference.cs >> this is the actual proxy class.
2. Config settings >> This gets updated with the Web Service Uri, binding info etc.

If you can port over just these 2 files to your unit test project, then it should work.

Comment: I fixed it by recreating the container and re uploading all the files to a separate folder.